# Access - Update em tabela sem utilização de módulo VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

Preciso atualizar uma tabela uma vez ao mês, no qual os dados inseridos deverão ser colocados no respectivo mês atual. Venho realizando isso via código VBA, porém, como a tabela possui aproximadamente 30 mil linhas, o processo é demorado. Gostaria de realizar o processo via Consulta do Access. Alguém ja enfrentou o mesmo problema? Caso não, existe maneiras de otimizar esse processo via código vba ?

Answer (score 1):

Você quer gravar os dados do excel no Access? Se for isso abaixo segue um exemplo de um método que recebe os dados do excel como parâmetros(pode ser implementado em um looping) e insere no Access.

```
Sub INSERT_EMAIL(protocolo, EMAIL)

    strConOracle = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\db.accdb" 
    Set oConOracle1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConOracle1.Open strConOracle


    'On Error Resume Next
    oConOracle1.Execute ("INSERT INTO TABELA_ACCESS (PROTOCOLO,END_EMAIL) VALUES  (" & protocolo & " , """ & EMAIL & """ ) ")



    oConOracle1.Close
    Set oConOracle1 = Nothing


End Sub
```